# Is there a reliable way to get the name of a Plugin's JAR file?

Tags: java, jar, minecraft, bukkit

Using the bukkit API, is it possible to make a call that would do something like the following pseudocode:

```
Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("PluginName").getJarFile();
```

Where for a plugin like MobBountyReloaded, it would return `plugins/MobBountyReloaded_v235.jar`.

I tried just looking for files using well-known naming-schemes like just appending `.jar` or `<version>.jar` to the name of the plugin, but that doesn't always yield correct results. The above example fails because the version number in the `plugin.yml` file is just `235` and not `_v235`, and some plugins use schemes like `<PluginName>-<Version>-<buildnumber>.jar`.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? The File information for every loaded plugin must be *somewhere* in memory, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a class loaded from the plugin, you can use the code source feature to get the jar from which the class was loaded.

```
Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("PluginName").getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Answer (score 1):

in your org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin subclass,

```
this.getFile().getAbsoluteFile();
```

returns full jar file name with path
where just this.getFile() returns something like this:
"plugins\clj-minecraft-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar"

in my case I needed this:
"file:/S:/cb/plugins/memorystone-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" as an URL(not URI)
which was:
this.getFile().toURI().toURL();

tested in [org.bukkit/bukkit "1.4.5-R0.3-SNAPSHOT"]

Comment: you can't do this though (method is not visible):((JavaPlugin)Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("PluginName")).getFile();